# ffplay play h265 video BUG

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

#### Test environment:

Two computers, both are WIN10X64

- Nvidia GT1030
- Intel630 + Nvidia 2070

The same ffplay.exe file; plays the same H265 video file。

#### Test Results

```
ffplay -hwaccel cuda -fs f:\video\x265.mp4
```

- Normal play.
- Unable to play normally, stuck. Error message：

  ```
  [AVHWDeviceContext @ 09f32900] Could not derive CUDA device.
  [hevc @ 09f27740] decoder->cudl->cuCtxPushCurrent(decoder->cuda_ctx) failed -> CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE: invalid argument
  [hevc @ 09f27740] Failed setup for format cuda: hwaccel initialisation returned error.
  ```

---

```
ffplay -vcodec hevc_cuvid -fs f:\video\x265.mp4
```

- Unable to play normally, stuck; no error message；
- Normal play；